# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when Copying Data from two tables into one table

Tags: mysql

I recieve an error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" when i try to run this script

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS VALUES (
(SELECT COMPANY_NAME FROM SUPPLIER),
(SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM PRODUCT)
);
```

Im trying to copy all records of two columns from two different tables into another Table.

i did some research and cant find any solutions without using a WHERE clause to add specific values such as where COMPANY_NAME = 'Alice';

EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS (

        COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY',
        PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY' ,
        TOTAL_PRODUCTS VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY',
        CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(COMPANY_NAME) ,
        CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_NAME) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME)

        );
```

```
UPDATE COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS
        SET TOTAL_PRODUCTS = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALPRODUCTS
        FROM PRODUCT);
```

Comment: Are you sure your `COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS` table only has two columns?

Comment: I would also expect that One company would produce more than One Product. Again you need to think again

Comment: Sorry see my EDIT, i added my table and an Update statement. @Smutje

Comment: Sorry see my EDIT, i added my table and an Update statement. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Yes, that confirms my assumption - you are omitting the column `TOTAL_PRODUCTS` from your insert statement.

Comment: @Smutje what do you by Omitting the column?

Comment: Please see my answer - you are using an "implicit insert" but you are not specifying which value should be inserted into the `TOTAL_PRODUCTS` column.

Comment: @Smutje ah that makes sense, i did wonder why the solutions i found has no Specified Columns. But when i do fix it it wants me to use an AS clause.

Comment: @Smutje i fixed this issue but now it says my Subquery returns more than one row. is it not possible to insert all values?

Comment: Do you want to create one entry per combination of company and product? I am not sure if this is possible with SQL.

Comment: @Smutje well this is the question i was given "Create a new relational table to store information about the company names of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier. Enforce, the appropriate consistency constraints on the new table. Next, copy into the new tableinformation about the company names of all suppliers and the total number of products
supplied by each supplier. " im only doing what i feel the question is asking

Comment: @Smutje Im just getting the count of Products and the Company Names really

Comment: @Smutje You can fix this if i had a WHERE clause by using IN but im unsure if that would work with what i want to do

Comment: I think you misread the question, as it is stated that you should calculate the total number of products by company and put this information in a new table - whilst there is no mentioning of any "product name" at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert data into a table without specifying the column names SQL implies you are aware of the number of columns and that you are using them in the right order. But if you omit one or more columns, you get the aforementioned error.

To enable inserting without the need to specify values for all columns, rewrite the statement similar to

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS(COMPANY_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME)
VALUES((SELECT COMPANY_NAME FROM SUPPLIER), (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM PRODUCT))
```

Comment: Check my 2 comments above and you may wish to rethink this answer

Comment: No, OP didn't write anything about data integrity, but he will see soon :-D My answer is only about syntactic correctness, not semantic.

Comment: :) Remind me never to ask you for help.... Just in case you give some to me :) :)

Comment: Sorry see my EDIT, i added my table and an Update statement. @Smutje

Comment: @Smutje What we cannot have a little humour amongst outselves ? :)

Comment: The syntax is not correct. The original query can at least run with some conditions.

Comment: The original query can't work because OP omits one column from his implicit insert

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hey mate could you possible take a look at the above comments under my question